# Where is mosquitto source directory located?

Tags: linux, debian, source, mqtt

I want to compile mosquitto-auth-plugin, which requires configuration of `config.mk` file, where one of the  required parameter is to Specify the path to the Mosquitto sources `MOSQUITTO_SRC =`.Could you please advice which directory i have to indicate if mosquitto was installed using advanced package tool (apt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck in the same issue a while ago but got the solution.
You may have installed mosquitto by `sudo apt-get install mosquitto` so the mosquitto libraries were not installed by default.

You need to install libmosquitto by `sudo apt-get install libmosquitto-dev` and then include the path as `/usr/include` in the config.mk (in MOSQUITTO_SRC=) file of auth-plugin as 'mosquitto.h' file is there.

In the end go to the auth-plugin directory and then first run `make clean` and finally `make` to compile the plugin.

Comment: Didn't check this for `mosquitto`, but usually the `-dev` package has the **header files** (and other stuff necessary for compiling), while the **libraries** are installed as part of the other packages. At least this is the case for all Debian packages I've used so far.